# React Context API, set context state from Child Components instead of passing functions as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

The React documentation says to pass the function defined in the Root component as a prop to the Child Component if you plan to update context from a nested component.

I have implemented the same:

```
import React from 'react';

const DataContext = React.createContext();

/**
 * The App.
 */
export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.updateGreet = this.updateGreet.bind( this );

        this.state = {
            greet: '',
            updateGreet: this.updateGreet
        }
    }

    updateGreet() {
        this.setState({
            greet: 'Hello, User',
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <DataContext.Provider value={ this.state }>
                <GreetButton />
                <DisplayBox />
            </DataContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}

/**
 * Just a button element. On clicking it sets the state of `greet` variable.
 */
const GreetButton = () => {
    return (
        <DataContext.Consumer>
            {
                ( { updateGreet } ) => {
                    return <button onClick={ updateGreet }>Greet</button>
                }
            }
        </DataContext.Consumer>
    )
}

/**
 * Prints the value of `greet` variable between <h1> tags.
 */
const DisplayBox = () => {
    return (
        <DataContext.Consumer>
            {
                ( { greet } ) => {
                    return <h1>{ greet }</h1>
                }
            }
        </DataContext.Consumer>
    )
}
```

It's a very simple React App I created for learning the Context API. What I'm trying to achieve is to define the `updateGreet()` method within the `GreetButton` component instead of defining it inside the `App` component since the function has nothing to do with the `App` component.

Another advantage I see is that if I choose to remove the `GreetButton` component altogether, then I need not keep track of all the methods it uses defined within another components.

Is there a way we can achieve this?

Comment: You can pass `setState` and define methods anywhere (wow - you can extend possibilities on the fly) ... but probably you don't know what context is intended for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that the `updateGreet` method *does* have to do with `App` since it is manipulating `App` state.

I don't see this as a context-specific issue so much as the normal react practice of passing functions down to child components.

To accomplish your wish you *could* bind and pass the `App`'s `setState` method to the provider and then implement `updateGreet` in the `GreetButton` component, but that would be an anti-pattern and I wouldn't recommend it.

When I am working with the Context API I typically define my context in a separate file and implement a custom provider to suit my needs, passing the related methods and properties down and consuming them throughout the tree as needed.

Essentially, implement what you have in `App` as its own *Provider* class `GreetProvider`. In the render method for `GreetProvider` simply pass the children through:

```
render() {
        return (
            <DataContext.Provider value={ this.state }>
                { this.props.children }
            </DataContext.Provider>
        )
    }
```

Now, all of your greeting logic can live together at the source, with the context. Use your new `GreetProvider` class in `App` and any of its children will be able to consume its methods.